# Null values in timestamp StructField

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I handle null values in Timestamp column ?

I have source data saved in List (result of sql)

```
List([222,1,222,222,2012-01-28 23:37:06.0,()], 
     [220,1,220,220,2012-04-24 23:37:08.0,()], 
     [220,1,220,220,2008-03-18 15:06:09.0,()],
     ...
```

In the last column are null values mixed with timestamps.

But when I try to load this as RDD

```
//Create RDD
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(res.toList)

// Create schema fields
val fields = List (StructField("value", StringType, nullable = true)
                  ,StructField("hit_count", IntegerType, nullable = true)
                  ,StructField("range_start", StringType, nullable = true)
                  ,StructField("range_end", StringType, nullable = true)
                  ,StructField("valid_from", TimestampType, nullable = true)
                  ,StructField("valid_to", TimestampType, nullable = true))

// Create DataFrame
val dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, StructType(fields))
```

I'm getting exception

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit is not
>   a valid external type for schema of timestamp

So Null values are wrapped as BoxedUnit which have different type other than TimestampType.

How can I handle this ? Is it possible to have mixed datatypes in one column, or do I have to map all null values into "null timestamp" ?

Comment: Could you please describe the structure of the _input_ list values (`[222,1,222,222,2012-01-28 23:37:06.0,()]`)? Which is the data type of each entry corresponding to a row? Which is the type of the cells inside?

Comment: How are you generating that list?  That's where the problem lies.  You have `Unit` values in that column instead of `null`s. (are there any time stamps in the column at all or is it all `Unit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `scala.runtime.BoxedUnit` dataType in your `res` data ([222,1,222,222,2012-01-28 23:37:06.0,**()**])

And thats **the main cause of the exception** you are facing when you are **applying schema of timestamp to the BoxedUnit**

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit is not a valid external type for schema of timestamp

So what you can do is *type check* in the `rdd` and if `BoxedUnit` is found then you can replace with valid `timestamp`. For testing I have used the `valid_from` timestamp

```
//Create RDD
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(res)
  .map(row => Row(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), if(row(5).isInstanceOf[BoxedUnit]) row(4) else row(5)))
```

all I have done is added a map where *type check* is done

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: This works !  
When I did 

`val rdd = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(res.toList).map(row => Row(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), if(row(5).isInstanceOf[BoxedUnit]) null else row(5)))` I've got exactly what I wanted. 

Thank you very much.